# How to distinguish between black and white chessboard squares

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to automatize the process of classifying the squares of chessboard images as black or white square. The step further would be to distinguish if it's an empty square or if the square is containing a piece. So far, I get close to classify every square as white or black using the average intensity of the center of the square but it's difficult setting a threshold. For the step further(empty squares or with a piece) I tried with `std2` but also there it's was difficult.

Here is my original image, and what I got close to so far
[image]
[image]

Here's is my script:

```
image = imerode(original,strel('disk',3));
image = imadjust(image,[],[],2);
figure,imshow(image),hold on;
for i = 1:length(cells)
  TL = cells(i).TL; %Cell's corner top left
  TR = cells(i).TR; %Cell's corner top right
  BL = cells(i).BL; %Cell's corner bottom left
  BR = cells(i).BR; %Cell's corner bottom right
  x = [TL(1) TR(1) BR(1) BL(1)];
  y = [TL(2) TR(2) BR(2) BL(2)];
  bw = poly2mask(x,y,size(image,1),size(image,2));
  measurements = regionprops(bw,'BoundingBox');
  cropped = imcrop(image, measurements.BoundingBox);
  m = regionprops(bw,'Centroid');
  x = m.Centroid(1);
  y = m.Centroid(2);
  w = 25; %width
  h = 25; %height
  tl = [round(x-w/2) round(y-h/2)];
  center = image(tl(1):tl(1)+w,tl(2):tl(2)+h,:);
  %stds(i) = std2(center);
  avgs(i) = mean2(center);
  if(avgs(i) > 55)
      str = "W";
  else
      str = "B";
  end
  text(x,y,str,'Color','red','FontSize',16);
end
```

**EDIT:** Image below is the new result after

```
image = imerode(image,strel('disk',4));
image = image>160;
```

[image]

Comment: see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/PlayChessWithAWebCam/BoardFinder for a non-matlab solution using OpenCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Matlabs build in checkerboard methods `detectCheckerboardPoints` and `checkerboard` to find the size of the checkerboard and construct a new one of the appropriate size. As there can only exist two possible checkerboards, construct both and check which one matches the best.

```
img = imread('PNWSv.jpg'); %Load image

%Prepare image
I = rgb2gray(img);
I2 = imerode(I,strel('square',10));
bw = imbinarize(I2,'adaptive');

%Find checkerboard points
[imagePoints,boardSize] = detectCheckerboardPoints(bw);

%Find the size of the checkerboard fields
x = boardSize(2)-1;
y = boardSize(1)-1;
fields = cell(y,x);
for k = 1:length(imagePoints)
    [i,j] = ind2sub([y,x],k);
    fields{i,j} = imagePoints(k,:);
end
avgDx = mean(mean(diff(cellfun(@(x) x(1),fields),1,2)));
avgDy = mean(mean(diff(cellfun(@(x) x(2),fields),1,1)));

%Construct the two possibilities
ref1 = imresize(imbinarize(checkerboard),[avgDx,avgDy]*8);
ref2 = imcomplement(ref1);

%Check which ones fits the better
c1 = normxcorr2(ref1,I);
c2 = normxcorr2(ref2,I);

if max(c2(:))<max(c1(:))
    ref=ref1;
    c = c1;
else 
    ref=ref2;
    c = c2;
end

%Plot the checkerboard bounding box on top of the original image
[ypeak, xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));
yoffSet = ypeak-size(ref,1);
xoffSet = xpeak-size(ref,2);

imshow(img);
imrect(gca, [xoffSet+1, yoffSet+1, size(ref1,2), size(ref1,1)]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this. However, I get this issue: 

Warning: The checkerboard must be asymmetric: one side should be even, and the other should be odd. Otherwise,
the orientation of the board may be detected incorrectly. 


Undefined function or variable 'ypeak2'.

Comment: I have updated the answer to take care of the error. Regarding the warning, you can simply ignore it. It is only used to measure the size of the fields and thus the board. So it does not matter if it confuses the direction or does not find all. See this page for how to suppress the warning (do not suppress all)

Comment: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html

Comment: Thank you very much, you did extra of what I asked! The correct scheme of black and white squares is in ref

Answer (score 1):

Erosion followed by binarization will help you find the empty white squares.

From these, you can reconstruct the whole chessboard grid more easily and estimate the occupied squares.

[image]

Comment: "You can reconstruct... and estimate.." is a good direction, but not an answer...

Comment: @Adiel: thank you for the constructive contribution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what strel did you use to erode? Because when I'm binarizing the top-left squares of the chessboard become all whites, losing their blackness

Comment: Aren't you dilating instead ? Did you adjust the threshold level.

Comment: I have edited the question, with the new result after erosion followed by binarization. Still on the right I get some white squares labeled as black. So I tried to lower the threshold but then some black squares get labeled as white on the top left

Comment: You can now add some weight from doing `std` on the original image

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean please? Because I get similar std value from those squares in the top right of the chessboard, both for black and white squares

Comment: You can use that the white (1) and black (0) fields alternate, starting from the top left corner and moving right there are only 2 possibilities, 1,0,1,0,... and 0,1,0,1,... as your suggested sequence is 1,0,1,0 it is the first which should be chosen.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, the problem is that the chessboards could be rotated @NickyMattsson

Comment: How does that posses a problem, I presume that you have to do this every time you load the chessboard in? You just check the suggested sequence, against the two possible every time, no matter how you rotate the chessboard, black and white always alternate.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean @NickyMattsson but I must be sure that the top left square is white(or black for another case). For this case I obtain that the top left square is white through my code above, but those squares on the right I get some white square as black. What if with another chessboard I get an erroneous color of the top left square? My sequence as you suggested would be not correct

Comment: You have to check the entire sequence against the two possible, not just the first field, e.g. by using `norm(ref1-sug)`, where `ref1` is the first possible sequence and `ref2` is the other and `sug` is the suggested sequence. Then you pick the reference (ref1 or ref2) which yields the lower norm.  Then you just need that more than half are correct.